# Keystroke Fn (function) key in Applescript

Tags: applescript, voice-recognition, keystroke, keystrokes

Is there any way to keystroke the Fn key in apple script? Ideally I would like to be able to "press it" twice in order to launch voice typing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if the script is run with a keyboard shortcut
tell application "System Events"
    key code 63 -- fn
    key code 63
end tell
```

See Events.h or [my website](http://lri.me/applescript.html) for the key codes.

Comment: Works perfectly! Do you by chance know how to open a folder through apple script? I think my problem is the spaces in the file path... /Users/username/Library/Speech/Speakable Items

Answer (score 0):

In an applescript your file path has to be a macpath not a unixpath i.e., separate the directories with a colon (not a forward slash) e.g.,

```
tell application "Finder"
    open folder "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Library:Speech:Speakable Items"
end tell
```